# How many years old am I?

Tags: knowledge

My age squared is the number of commandments in the Torah minus the year in George Orwell's Book. When subtracting, consider the cause of the Y2K problem.

How old am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 613 commandments in the torah.

1984, considering Y2K is 84.

613-84=529

sqrt (529) = 23

Your age is 23.

Comment: I know I said I was leaving... but I just dropped in for something else and saw this one which was screaming at me to be solved...

Comment: Lol, awesome. Good work.